# Find the largest N digit number in a W by H grid of digits

Tags: code-golf, math, number, grid

Write a program or function that takes in a positive integer \$N\$ and a grid of decimal digits (\$0\$ to \$9\$) with width \$W\$ and height \$H\$ (which are also positive integers). You can assume that \$N\$ will be less than or equal to the larger of \$W\$ and \$H\$ (\$N \le \max(W,H)\$).

Print or return the largest contiguous \$N\$-digit number that appears horizontally or vertically in the grid, written in normal reading order or in reverse.

- Diagonal lines of digits are not considered.
- The grid does not wrap around, i.e. it does not have
  periodic boundary conditions.

For example, the \$3\times3\$ grid

```
928
313
049
```

would have `9` as the output for \$N = 1\$, `94` as the output for \$N = 2\$, and `940` as the output for \$N = 3\$.

The \$4\times3\$ grid

```
7423
1531
6810
```

would have `8` as the output for \$N = 1\$, `86` for \$N = 2\$, `854` for \$N = 3\$, and `7423` for \$N = 4\$.

The \$3\times3\$ grid

```
000
010
000
```

would have output `1` for \$N = 1\$, and `10` for N = 2 and N = 3 (`010` is also valid for N = 3).

The \$1\times1\$ grid

```
0
```

would have output `0` for \$N = 1\$.

You can take the input in any convenient reasonable format. e.g. the grid could be a newline separated string of digits, or a multidimensional array, or a list of lists of digits, etc. Leading zeros are allowed in the output if they were part of the grid.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins, but I'll also award brownie points (i.e. more likely upvotes) for answers that can show that their algorithm is computationally efficient.

Comment: Are we allowed to print any leading zeroes?

Comment: @Pietu1998 "Leading zeros are allowed in the output if they were part of the grid."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>22</s> 19 bytes

*3 bytes thanks to Jakube.*

```
seSs.:RQ.n,L_MdCB.z
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=seSs.%3ARQ.n%2CL_MdCB.z&input=3%0A7423%0A1531%0A6810&debug=0)

If we are allowed to print leading zeroes, the code is 18 bytes:

```
eSs.:RQ.n,L_MdCB.z
```

Comment: Converting a string with leading zeros to an integer can be accomplished with `s`.

Answer (score 9):

### CJam, <s>39</s> <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
qN/)i\[{zW%_}4*]ff{_,@e<ew:i}e_:e>
```

Just quickly, before @Dennis wakes up :P

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%29i%5C%5B%7BzW%25_%7D4*%5Dff%7B_%2C%40e%3Cew%3Ai%7De_%3Ae%3E&input=7423%0A1531%0A6810%0A4).

#### Explanation

The basic algorithm is to take all four rotations of the grid and split each row into chunks of length `N` (or the row length, whichever's smaller). Then convert the chunks to ints and take the largest.

```
qN/             Split input by newlines, giving an array of lines
)i\             Drop N from the array and put at bottom
[        ]      Wrap in array...
 {    }4*         Perform 4 times...
  zW%_              Rotate grid anticlockwise and push a copy
                Note that this gives an array of 5 grids [CCW1 CCW2 CCW3 CCW4 CCW4]
ff{         }   For each grid row, mapping with N as an extra parameter...
   _,             Push length of row
     @e<          Take min with N
        ew        Split into chunks
          :i      Convert to ints
e_              Flatten that array
:e>             Take cumulative max
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `few` do anything special, or is it three separate commands?

Comment: @ETHproductions It's actually the operator `ew` applied using `f`, or "map with extra parameter". For example, `["abcd" "efgh"] 2 few` results in `[["ab" "bc" "cd"] ["ef" "fg" "gh"]]`.

Comment: Gotcha :) That's an interesting coincidence, though.

Comment: Only issue is that, when @Dennis wakes up, everybody else loses anyway. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ZU$4Ð¡Ẏṡ€ḌFṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8qVMXk8IRDCx/u6nu4c@GjpjUPd/S4PdzZ8P/w8kcb1yn5HNod5aNyrAso4Q3Ekf//R3NxRkdb6hjpWMTqcHEqRBvrGOoYQ5gGOiY6lrFANkiJOZBjBJMx1DHVASqEcMx0LIB6DGAKDXSAEGaAIYJpgKQkNpYrFgA)

This takes the grid as an \$W\times H\$ matrix of single digits.

The TIO Footer simply takes each input list and generates the outputs for each \$N = 1, 2, ...\$ up to either \$W\$ or \$H\$, depending on which is larger

### How it works

```
ZU$4Ð¡Ẏṡ€ḌFṀ - Main link. Takes the matrix M on the left and N on the right
  $          - Group the previous 2 links together as a monad f(M):
Z            -   Transpose
 U           -   Reverse
   4Ð¡       - 4 times, run f(M) on M, updating M each time, and return all 4 results
               This yields M, Mᵀ with rows reversed, Mᵀ and M with rows reversed
      Ẏ      - Tighten into a list of lists
        €    - Over each:
       ṡ     -   Yield all overlapping sublists of length N
         Ḍ   - Convert back to integers
          F  - Flatten
           Ṁ - Maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
DÅ|«€ÂJ€Œ˜sùà
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5XBrzaHVj5rWHG7yApJHJ52eU3x45@EF//9HRyuZK@koKJmACCMQYawUq6MQrWQIYptCBICEIUTUDMS2gAgACQOl2FguIwA) Explanation:

```
D                 # duplicate matrix
 Å|               # get column vectors
   «              # join matrix with its column vectors
    €Â            # append reversed elements
      J           # join arrays into numbers
       €Œ˜        # Get all substrings
          sù      # Keep only those of required length
            à     # Get the largest value
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes the matrix as an array of lines. Includes leading `0`s in the output, where applicable.

```
4Æ=z)mãVÃc ñ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&header=cVI&code=NMY9eilt41bDYyDx&input=IjkyOAozMTMKMDQ5Igox)

```
4Æ=z)mãVÃc ñ    :Implicit input of array U & integer V
4Æ              :Map the range [0,4)
  =             :  Reassign to U
   z            :  Rotate 90° clockwise
    )           :  End reassignment
     m          :  Map
      ãV        :    Substrings of length V
        Ã       :End map
         c      :Flatten
           ñ    :Sort
                :Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
▲ṁX⁰Σ↑4¡om↔T²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9odXNr/@KCgcK2/@KWsuG5gVjigbDOo@KGkTTCoW9t4oaUVMKy////Mv85MjgKMzEzCjA0OQ)

The arguments are a bit finicky here.